# Allow shortcode in buddypress profile field

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am using a Wordpress website with the following plugins : 
- Buddypress
- Userpro
- Booked Appointment

Now, I would like the user to be able to simply paste a calendar's Shortcode like : [booked-calendar calendar=27] in the "Biography" field of their profile (buddypress / userpro).

However, it doesn't display the calendar from the plugin as it should be even if the field is HTML allowed.

Any suggestion to make these field accept shortcodes ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddypress and Userpro are separate but sync. You may have to add some function to buddypress functions.php file to allow shortcodes in the profile field.

Comment: Hello, when I use the Buddypress' native "Profile" view of a user's profile it display my shortcode, but not when I use the override version from Userpro. 
They are absolutely not answering my questions for months now so I try here. Any idea where I could add this ? It seems that even allowing the HTML in the fields don't give you the abilities of the WYSIWYG editor...
Thanks !